Can't Install Package with Conda
I am trying to install the porechop_abi package from the bioconda channel. I can see the package is available when I look online at the bioconda GitHub. However, I get a PackagesNotFoundError when I run:
conda install -c bioconda porechop_abi 

The same happens when running:
conda search -c bioconda porechop_abi 

I've tried cleaning and updating conda and that didn't help. When running the install with the -vvv option, the following is where things seem to go wrong:
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __archspec
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __osx
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __unix
done
Solving environment: ...working... DEBUG conda.resolve:get_reduced_index(673): Retrieving packages for: 
  - porechop_abi
unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/labuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 316, in install
    unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/labuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 154, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/labuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 215, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/labuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 380, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._add_specs(ssc)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/labuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 733, in _add_specs
    explicit_pool = ssc.r._get_package_pool(self.specs_to_add)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/labuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 653, in _get_package_pool
    pool = self.get_reduced_index(specs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/labuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 84, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/labuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 678, in get_reduced_index
    explicit_specs, features = self.verify_specs(explicit_specs)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/labuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 333, in verify_specs
    raise ResolvePackageNotFound(bad_deps)
conda.exceptions.ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - porechop_abi

Does anyone have any ideas?

what is your OS and architecture, is it MacOS, arm64 by any chance?

Yes, it's an M1 chip with arm64 architecture. I realized this recently, and have fixed this issue by creating a conda environment using the osx-64 subdirectory. Using this environment, I successfully installed porechop as well as a lot of other libraries I had had issues with previously.
